# Get_File_contents and MINE TYPE 

Tags: php

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents('http://domain.com/background.gif');
echo $file;
?>
```

it echo a very long string(GIF89aÅÕ2cŒ®³¾J}BvUyš±µÁJr•O€d,,,,), not a image, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify content-type HTTP header:

```
header('Content-type: image/gif');
```

Otherwise browser treats output as a regular text/html web page.

Note, that headers should be sent *before* any output of your PHP script. Se [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) for more info about headers.

Answer (score 1):

```
header('Content-type:image/gif");
```

insert this before echo